# Error while running "drush st"

Tags: 8, drush

On a Linux system I installed Drush 7 with Composer. When I try to use it with Drupal 8 alpha-11, for example running `drush st`, I get this error. I looked around but I can't find anything about it.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Site\Settings' not found in /home/$USER/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc on line 278
> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Site\Settings' not found in /home/$USER/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc on line 278
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
> Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Site\Settings' not found in /home/$USER/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc, line 278

Comment: I have a similar problem with Drupal 8.0.2. My error is: Fatal error: Class 'Psr\Log\AbstractLogger' not found in /Users/$USER/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Log/Logger.php on line 31 . I suppose this is related with drush running outside the Drupal tree. But I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue. Upgrading Drupal 8 to the latest change (8.x branch instead of the alpha11 version) Drush works properly.